# custom annotation is not appearing without setting image

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I am trying to create custom annotation as each annotation save some data which i need to show on tap of pin. But i need to show default ios pin image. Everything is working fine but pin will only show when i set any image. without setting image it is not showing default ios pin. My code is
 CustomAnnotation.h file

```
    @interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *title;
    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *subTitle;
    @property(nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UserDevice *userData;
    -(instancetype)initWithUserData:(UserDevice *)userData;
```

on mapViewC.h

```
-(void)addMarkersOnMap{
for (UserDevice* userDevice in markersArray) {
    CustomAnnotation *point = [[CustomAnnotation alloc]initWithUserData:userDevice];
    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userDevice.latitude, userDevice.longitude);
    point.userData = userDevice;
    point.title = @"dszf";
    [mapview addAnnotation:point];       
    MKMapRect mapRect = [self getZoomingRectOnMap:mapview toFitAllOverlays:YES andAnnotations:YES includeUserLocation:NO];
    [mapview setVisibleMapRect:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0) animated:YES];
}

}
#pragma mark - MKMapView Delegate methods

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    return nil;
}
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) {
    CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = annotation;
    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotationViewID"];
    if (customAnnotationView == nil){
        customAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotationViewID"];
    }
    //        customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-1"];
    customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true;
    customAnnotationView.annotation = customAnnotation;
    return customAnnotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: for pin on map, you have to use MKPinAnnotation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CustomAnnotationView` use `MKPinAnnotationView` in your `viewForAnnotation` `MKMapViewDelegate` method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]]) {
        CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = annotation;
        MKPinAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"annotationViewID"];
        if (customAnnotationView == nil){
            customAnnotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annotationViewID"];
        }
        //        customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin-1"];
        customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true;
        customAnnotationView.annotation = customAnnotation;
        return customAnnotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
  CustomAnnotation *customAnnotation = annotation;
  NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"PinViewAnnotation"; 
  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: annotationIdentifier]; 

  if (pinView ==nil) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation: customAnnotation reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier];

    }
   pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; // change color
   pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
   pinView.enabled = YES;
   mapView selectAnnotation:pinView animated:YES];
```